# Is there a way to directly import the best fit parameters of a function, obtained using Gnuplot, to python? (Please read details)

Tags: python-2.7, gnuplot

So I’m using Gnuplot to fit some data sets to some function and I’m using python for most of the programming stuff. The problem is I have to calculate the best fit parameter each time in Gnuplot and then manually type it in a python list. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use scipy to fit the data from within python. Another option is to write gnuplot output to a file, and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell gnuplot to write the output in a specific file. For example:

```
set fit errorvariables # creates a_err type variables for fitting errors
set print "tmp.dat"
print a,a_err,b,b_err
```

Then you can tell python to read tmp.dat in some specific line. Take a look at the documentation for print and sprintf